# Capturing signatures in an iOS app

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

We have a need to capture signatures from an iOS app – the use case is letting the user draw their signature with their finger directly onto the screen. I’m more of a web guy so my default approach would be to embed a web view and use canvas to let the user draw, then capturing a PNG with `toDataURL`. A native Cocoa control would probably be nicer though. Are there any pre-built solutions out there, or an easy API to use? I note that the kanji input on iOS lets you draw characters on your phone: is this API available for use or is it private?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do that using Core Graphics. Here is a [tutorial](https://web.archive.org/web/20161026173835/https://www.ifans.com/forums/threads/tutorial-drawing-to-the-screen.132024/).

Comment: Thanks Vignesh, that’s a great starting point for what we’re trying to do.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a library that you can use as a starting point: https://github.com/IngmarStein/SignatureDemo

Disclaimer: it's my fork of Jason Harwigs free SignatureDemo project

Comment: Thanks for posting your answer! Please be sure to read the [FAQ on Self-Promotion](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion) carefully. Also note that it is *required* that you post a disclaimer every time you link to your own site/product.

Comment: Hi Sir, I have been using Signature Demo app for my applicaitons.I was getting 10 errors in NISignatureView.Please give us the updated file for iOS 8 and Xcode6.0.Please give us the new updated SignatureDemo app.